# Can a functional be expressed by an inner product in an infinite-dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Question first, motivation afterwards.

> Let $P$ be the vector space of all real polynomials (with no restriction on the degree).  Is there an inner product $\langle p\!\mid\!q\rangle$ on $P$, and a fixed polynomial $q\in P$, such that
>   $$\langle p\!\mid\!q\rangle=p(0)$$
>   for all $p\in P$?

**Motivation**.  This kind of thing is always possible on a finite-dimensional space $V$ over the field $F=\Bbb R$ or $F=\Bbb C$: moreover, even if the inner product is specified, and a linear functional $\phi:V\to F$ is specified (replacing the map $p\mapsto p(0)$), one can always find a suitable $q$.

It can also sometimes be done in infinite dimensional spaces: for example, if
$$\langle p\!\mid\!q\rangle=\int_{-1}^1 p(x)q(x)\,dx\quad\hbox{and}\quad \phi(p)=\int_{-1}^1 p(x)\,dx\ ,$$
then obviously $\langle p\!\mid\!1\rangle=\phi(p)$ for all $p$.

If the functional is $p\mapsto p(0)$ then the "obvious attempt" is something like
$$\langle p\!\mid\!q\rangle=p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+\cdots\ ,$$
but this will not converge.

I was given an answer to this question which went something like "blah blah Hilbert space blah blah" and which I didn't understand at all, so it would be great if that could be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generalize Ian's answer: if you have *any* real vector space $V$ and *any* functional $\alpha:V\to\mathbb{R}$, you can put an inner product on $V$ such that there is an element $q\in V$ such that $\alpha(p)=\langle p\mid q\rangle$.  Indeed, you may assume $\alpha\neq 0$, and choose a vector $q\in V$ such that $\alpha(q)=1$.  Now let $B$ be a basis for $\ker(\alpha)$; then $C=B\cup\{q\}$ is a basis for $V$.  Take the inner product on $V$ induced by this basis (i.e., to compute the inner product, expand each vector with respect to the basis and then take the dot product of their coefficients).  Since $\alpha$ vanishes on every basis vector except $q$ and $\alpha(q)=1$, $\alpha(p)$ is just the coefficient of $q$ in the basis expansion of $p$ for all $p\in V$.  That is, $\alpha(p)=\langle p\mid q\rangle$.

Comment: Extremely clear, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Each polynomial's coefficients form a member of $\ell^2$ when extended with zeros. Then you use the standard $\ell^2$ inner product with $q $ isomorphic to $(1,0,0,\dots) $, i.e. $q=1$.

Comment: To put it a little differently: the critical thing about your polynomials is that they're zero after *finitely many* coefficients. If you'd instead allowed the possibility of "infinite polynomials" (like Taylor series), then this approach might not work. This also raises another question: is there such a $q$ for *any* inner product rather than for the standard inner product on $\ell^2$? I ought to have an answer to that, but I don't. :(

Comment: Thanks @Ian.  What is the standard $\ell^2$ inner product?

Comment: @David: For this case, we can express it as follows: given $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ and $q(x) = \sum_{i=0}^m b_i x^i$, set $\langle p \mid q \rangle := \sum_{i=1}^{\min(n,m)} a_i b_i$.

Comment: @JohnHughes: No, there needn't exist such a $q$ for a general inner product; only if your evaluation functional is *bounded* with respect to that inner product.  For instance, consider the $L^2([0,1])$ inner product $\langle p \mid q \rangle = \int_{0}^1 p(x)q(x)\,dx$.  If such $q$ were to exist, Cauchy-Schwartz would tell us $|p(0)| = |\langle p \mid q \rangle | \le \|p\| \|q\|$.  But by taking $p(x) = (1-x)^n$ for very large $n$, we see that we can have $p(0)=1$ while $\|p\| = \sqrt{\int_0^1 p(x)^2\,dx}$ is arbitrarily small.

Comment: Thanks, @NateEldredge -- that makes sense. Clear and simple (once you see it, of course!)

Comment: Thanks @NateEldredge, I was going to ask the general question next :)